# How to remove an element when using gravity forms?

Tags: javascript-objects

I'm trying to remove a widget from a form so that I can have the "date picker" in gravity forms be read only. I have already disabled text input for this gravity forms field, but a calendar widget provides a loophole to change the date anyway. This date picker widget may have been created based on a plug in that is installed (the plug-in is necessary for the proper function of the form for our company's purposes).

I'm wondering if there are any problems with my code, if there is another code I can try to remove the widget, or perhaps if this is an issue with gravity forms (if anyone knows the program that well).

I tested the following code in Google Chrome's console and I was able to successfully remove a calendar widget in the date picker:

```
var element = document.getElementById('ui-datepicker-div');element.parentNode.removeChild(element);
```

And then in the HTML field, according to gravity form's instructions, I inserted the code I had written between the following code that Gravity Forms Provided:

```
<script>
function myCustomJs() {
    return true;
}

function myCustomJs();
</script>
```

which produced this as the present code:

```
<script>
function myCustomJs() {
    return true;

var element = document.getElementById('ui-datepicker-div');element.parentNode.removeChild(element);

}

function myCustomJs();
</script>
```

But unfortunately, when I ran the preview, nothing happened (different than when I ran it in google chrome's developer console).

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is simple to disable the Gravity Forms datepicker for a specific field, I would recommend doing this with PHP.

```
add_filter( 'gform_field_content_123_4', function( $content ) {
    $content = str_replace( 'datepicker', '', $content );
    return $content;
} );
```

Update the `123` in the filter name to your form ID and the `4` to your Date field ID.

FYI, this is handled out-of-the-box with the [Gravity Forms Read Only](https://gravitywiz.com/documentation/gravity-forms-read-only/) plugin.

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't seem to work.  I realized that one think I overlooked is that the widget that appears when you click the field in question, the code for this is located in a separate java script section and is not located in the code beneath the field ID.  I am going to have to look into the code deeper to figure out how I can remove this function just from this field and  not from the entire website.

Comment: This will work. Try confirming that you've updated the filter name with your correct form and field ID and that the snippet is installed in your theme's functions.php file. Also to clarify, this snippet is field-specific so it will only disable the datepicker for the specified field (by field ID).